# idea: Blender real time collaboration? (like hytale's tool)

Tags: python, add-on

something like this: https://youtu.be/ROAeksqbLR8 could be great for blender, like a kinda "multiplayer" workflow where multiple users can interact with the same .blend file in real time.

is there a way to do this or something like an add-on?

Comment: short answer: no

Comment: The only time that I've heard of about a collaborative workflow in Blender was a talk  presented at the Blender Conference 2019: https://conference.blender.org/2019/presentations/529/